# angular *ngIf show the row only if an element in a column have a value exist

Tags: angular, mongodb, mean-stack

i want to show data of a server in a table but only if that server have an application on it else ignore it i tried to use *ngIf="(item.application?.application == 1)" but it didn't work
this is an example of the code

```
<tbody>
          <tr *ngFor="let item of mf.data"  >
            <div *ngIf="(item.application?.application == 1)">
              <td >{{item.serveur?.nomServeur}}</td>
              <td>{{item.application?.application}}</td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td></td>
              <td>
                <button type="button" [routerLink]="['/items/update',item._id]" class="btn btn-info"><i
                    class="fa fa-refresh fa-lgs"></i>
                </button>
                <button class="btn btn-danger" (click)="onDelete(item._id)"><i class="fa fa-remove fa-lg"></i>
                </button>
              </td>
            </div>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to use and `ng-container` to wrap the `*ngFor`. This will allow you to place the `*ngIf` directly on your `<tr>` element. The problem I see is that the `<tr>` will still be generated - only the contents will not be shown if the `*ngIf` is false.

Example:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of mf.data">
  <tr *ngIf="item.application?.application === 1">
   ...
  </tr>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: it didnt work nothing is showed in the table

Comment: @SpawN That must mean that your `item.application?.application` is never equal to 1! A good way to test the value is to add a new `<tr>item.application?.application</tr>` to validate the value without an `*ngIf`

Comment: i want to show it if it exist it doesnt have a fixed value

Comment: @SpawN The code I set above gives the basics for a nested ngFor and ngIf. If nothing is showing up then the `item.application` or nested entities never equal 1. If it's as simple as the entity existing, then you can use `*ngIf="!!item.application"`

Comment: thank ou so much that was so helpful the poblem application could be
` "appliation": [   "example" ], `
or  `  "appliation": [     ], ` and that didnt work

Comment: @z i found a way to resolve it i used **<tr *ngIf="!!item.application[0]">**
µthank you for your help i appreciate it